# Do while loop in Java using JOptionPane

Tags: java, do-while, joptionpane

I was trying to build a program that will determine if its negative or positive, so far its fine but it seems that my code doesn't read the negative numbers, only the positive ones, I can't find what's wrong with it.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class EYYY {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        int positive=0;
        int negative=0;
        int num=0;
        int loop = 1;

        while(loop<=5){


            Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number: "));
            if(num<0)
                negative++;

            if(num>=0)
                positive++;
            loop++;
        }

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Negative numbers in the program: " + negative + "\nPositive numbers in the program: " + positive);
      
    }
}
```

Comment: You never assigned the number you entered to the variable you are checking. you need to do `num =  Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number: "));`. Currently num is always 0 and you just throw away whatever is entered by the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `num=0;` cause to `num` value be always zero and positive but you need to store the input value of `JOptionPane` in `num` variable on each iteration of `while-loop` to check the new input value for negative or positive:

```
num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number: "));
```

complete code:

```
int positive = 0;
int negative = 0;
int num = 0;
int loop = 1;

while (loop <= 5) {

    num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number: "));
    if (num < 0)
        negative++;

    if (num >= 0)
        positive++;
    loop++;
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
        "Negative numbers in the program: " + negative + "\nPositive numbers in the program: " + positive);
```